# e.force:refreshView not refreshing component view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, refresh

I am using e.force:refreshView in order to refresh a custom component and it does not seem to be working. I am firing it when a flow finishes (that categorizes uploaded files) but the component does not refresh at all. Here is some of the relevent code

controller

```
handleFlowFinish: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fireRefresh(component, event, helper);

    console.log("It Fired!")
}
```

Helper

```
fireRefresh : function (component, event, helper) {
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    console.log("Triggered Sucessfully")

}
```

I originally had it in the Controller but thought it might make sense to fire it from the helper. Either way it does not refresh the component. Both Console.logs log through so the functions themselves are being fired

I can include more code if necessary but with th fact the both above functions trigger without issue it doesn't seem like it would add anything

Comment: Sounds like a known issue . https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDOuQAM . There is a workaround not sure if thats viable for you

Answer (score 3):

As @BrianMiller stated, `$A.get('e.force:refreshView')` only updates the standard components on the current lightning page.  But that's because those components are listening for the event.  I was able to get my custom Aura component to refresh when the event is fired by listening for it:

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

In my use case, my custom component exposes buttons to call one of two quick actions (via `actionAPI.invokeAction`); the quick actions are custom quick actions also implemented as Aura components, and each one fires a refresh (`$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();`) when finished.  I needed my component to refresh along with the standard layouts to change the buttons shown; listening for the event works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can call the init method once again which can re-fetch the data of an uploaded file and for any other records use caching. Make sure it does not go into a loop.

controller

```
handleFlowFinish: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fireRefresh(component, event, helper);

    console.log("It Fired!");
    var a = component.get('c.init');
    $A.enqueueAction(a);
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt loop in my situation as the flow is triggered by a user click and the init just retrieves displayed data so that should work. thank you

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, `$A.get('e.force:refreshView')` only updates the standard components on the current lightning page.  For example, if you're on a record page and have a custom component that updates record data, then using the `e.force:refreshView` will pull in the new values on the Record Details standard component.

As mentioned by @VivekMakkar, anytime you want to refresh content on your own lightning components, you need to handle that manually yourself.

Comment: I did not realize that it only updates the standard components but that would make a lot of sense. appreciate it